# Generate all unique k-subsequences

Tags: python, python-itertools, formal-languages, subsequence

I am trying to write a Python (at least initially) function to generate all subsequences of some length k (where k > 0). Since I only need unique subsequences, I am storing both the subsequences and partial subsequences in `set`s. The following, adapted from a colleague, is the best I could come up with. It seems...overly complex...and like I should be able to abuse `itertools`, or recursion, to do what I want to do. Can anyone do better?

```py
from typing import Set, Tuple


def subsequences(string: str, k: int) -> Set[Tuple[str, ...]]:
    if len(string) < k:
        return set()
    start = tuple(string[:k])
    result = {start}
    prev_state = [start]
    curr_state = set()
    for s in string[k:]:
        for p in prev_state:
            for i in range(k):
                new = p[:i] + p[i + 1 :] + (s,)
                curr_state.add(new)
        result.update(curr_state)
        prev_state = list(curr_state)
        curr_state.clear()
    return result
```

(For context, I am interested in induction of [k-strictly piecewise languages](https://www.cs.earlham.edu/~jrogers/mol11.pdf), an efficiently learnable subclass of the regular languages, and the grammar can be characterized by all licit k-subsequences.

Ultimately I am also thinking about doing this in C++, where `std::make_tuple` isn't quite as powerful as Python `tuple`.)

Comment: Could you add some examples? All subsequences of what?

Comment: Can you use https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations?

Comment: @DanielMesejo: All subsequences of some iterable (here typed to be a string). The 2-subsequences of `"foo"` are `{("f", "o"), ("o", "o")}` and the 3-subsequences of `"foobar"` are `{('o', 'b', 'r'), ('o', 'o', 'a'), ('f', 'b', 'a'), ('o', 'a', 'r'), ('f', 'o', 'o'), ('f', 'o', 'r'), ('b', 'a', 'r'), ('o', 'b', 'a'), ('f', 'a', 'r'), ('o', 'o', 'r'), ('f', 'b', 'r'), ('o', 'o', 'b'), ('f', 'o', 'b'), ('f', 'o', 'a')}`

Comment: @SyntaxVoid I suppose I could just do `frozenset(itertools.combinations(string, k))` but I wonder if it makes sense to avoid the intermediate computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a set of `r` combinations from `n` items (w/o replacement, `<= (n choose r)`.

**Given**

```
import itertools as it

import more_itertools as mit
```

**Code**

*Option 1* - [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
set(it.combinations("foo", 2))
# {('f', 'o'), ('o', 'o')}

set(it.combinations("foobar", 3))
# {('b', 'a', 'r'),
#  ('f', 'a', 'r'),
#  ('f', 'b', 'a'),
#  ('f', 'b', 'r'),
#  ('f', 'o', 'a'),
#  ('f', 'o', 'b'),
#  ('f', 'o', 'o'),
#  ('f', 'o', 'r'),
#  ('o', 'a', 'r'),
#  ('o', 'b', 'a'),
#  ('o', 'b', 'r'),
#  ('o', 'o', 'a'),
#  ('o', 'o', 'b'),
#  ('o', 'o', 'r')}
```

*Option 2* - [`more_itertools.distinct_combinations`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_combinations)

```
list(mit.distinct_combinations("foo", 2))
# [('f', 'o'), ('o', 'o')]

list(mit.distinct_combinations("foobar", 3))
# [('f', 'o', 'o'),
#  ('f', 'o', 'b'),
#  ('f', 'o', 'a'),
#  ('f', 'o', 'r'),
#  ('f', 'b', 'a'),
#  ('f', 'b', 'r'),
#  ('f', 'a', 'r'),
#  ('o', 'o', 'b'),
#  ('o', 'o', 'a'),
#  ('o', 'o', 'r'),
#  ('o', 'b', 'a'),
#  ('o', 'b', 'r'),
#  ('o', 'a', 'r'),
#  ('b', 'a', 'r')]
```

Both options yield the same (unordered) output.  However:

- Option 1 takes the set of all combinations (including duplicates)
- Option 2 does not compute duplicate intermediates

Install `more_itertools` via `> pip install more_itertools`.

See also a [rough implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of `itertools.combinations` in written Python.